# Debugging PHP Template Code in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I notice that the slightest error in PHP template code - like a missing ";" at the end of a statement - results in an unhelpful "Server error" screen when the code tries to run, without leaving any clue about what's wrong. I have

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

at the top of the script but that doesn't seem to kick in until the code at least parses.

So I'm wondering if there's a PHP lint function somewhere, so you could copy your code between a `<PHP` and `?>`, drop it into this lint page and it would tell you about a missing ";", an unmatched  "(" or "{", etc.

Comment: That's no answer to your question, but I suggest you use an IDE like PHPStorm that does the error checking before you upload the faulty file.

Comment: did you set [`WP_DEBUG`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Debug) to true?

Comment: No I didn't have WP_DEBUG set, and setting it does indeed show all  the PHP parse errors it finds.  Many thanks!